# Form elements ignore body CSS

Tags: css

I want to set a web page to dark mode, so I set the background to black and the font color to white in the body. My expectation is that this will be inherited by all elements in the body, which works for a div element and a nested div element and a form, but neither for a button nor for a select element.

This problem occurs in both Firefox Developer Edition 73.0b11 (64-bit) and Chromium 79.0.3945.130 Arch Linux.

I know I can specify the values again for buttons and select and option elements but *why* is this necessary? Why does a button not belong to the body?

```css
body
{ 
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

select
{
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    This is text in the body.
    <div>This is text in a div
      <div>This is text in a nested div</div>
    </div>
    <form>
      This is text in a form.
      <button>This is text in a button</button>
      <button style="background-color:black;color: white;">This is text in a button with inline style</button>
      <select multiple>
        <option>This is text in a select option</option>
        <option>This is text in a another select option</option>
        <option>This is text in a yet another select option</option>
      </select>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because the browser/vendor has some default styling of the input elements. Their selectors are more specific than your `body { ... }` selector, and that's why the override does not work unless you select for the elements explicitly, with a selector of the same or greater specificity.

Comment: @Terry: Never would have guess that, thanks for the fast answer! If you make a real answer out of it, I can accept it so the question gets closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further elabourate on my comment: browsers typically are opiniated with regards to styling of certain elements. In this case, they would have applied browser/vendor-specific styling to the input elements. As the styling contains selectors that are more specific that your `body { ... }` selector, the browser's default styling will override the colors you've set for body.

To circumvent this issue, you should style your input elements using selectors that are of the same specificity or greater than the browser's vendor styles.

Speaking of which, this is also why CSS resets are popular: because they remove/reset opiniated vendor-specific appearances on elements.

Answer (score 3):

**BROWSERS HAVE THEIR OWN STYLES**

By default each browser will define its own css styling for all common elements. This will include base colours, backgrounds, padding, margins etc.

**WHY?**

The browser vendors do this so they always have a fallback in case you fail to specify certain properties. If for instance you never set a body colour and background, is the browser supposed to render nothing?

**TAKING BACK CONTROL**

A common practice to handle this type of behaviour is to initiate a **CSS reset** at the start of your stylesheet to set generic attributes and *"reset"* the browser defined defaults. This is very popular because not all browser use the same defaults, this technique is a good way that you can not only define your defaults but you can ensure a consistant default styling across all browsers.

---

Here is an example of [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](https://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) 
*(One of the pioneers of this technique.)*

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

---

In your response to your exact query.

You can simply set `inherit` property on the items you want to apply the body styles to.

```
button,
select,
option {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

select {
  height: 5em;
}

button,
select,
option {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  This is text in the body.
  <div>This is text in a div
    <div>This is text in a nested div</div>
  </div>
  <form>
    This is text in a form.
    <button>This is text in a button</button>
    <button>This is text in a button with inline style</button>
    <select multiple>
      <option>This is text in a select option</option>
      <option>This is text in a another select option</option>
      <option>This is text in a yet another select option</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think answer will be approved with adding `background-color: inherit;` to bottom snippet and updated playable code snippet from the question. Lazy edit reviewers @Alfie and @LazerBass can't check the question to see the point.

Answer (score 1):

Things like buttons, links or inputs are specified by the browser which means that they are styled apart of the body. That is why the input to upload a file looks so ugly on some browsers or why it looks different from chrome to firefox.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance) you can see the specified rules for firefox styling.

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-default-button-styles/) you can see how to overwrite these default styles.